# snort fedora core x86_64 rules

Tags: snort

Does anyone know if where I can download the snort rules for Fedora Core 13 x86_64 not i386, if they even exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rule sets are available from

http://www.snort.org & 
http://www.bleedingsnort.com

I believe your talking about repositories in Fedora, because rule sets are not architecture specific.

Happy Hacking!

Comment: The precompiled so_rules seem to be.